# Chrome on Android renders unicode astrological characters as emoji, how can I disable that behavior (render them as normal characters)?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, unicode, emoji

If I write astrological unicode characters on a website, such as: ♈♉♊♋♌♍♎♏♐♑♒♓ (taken from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_sign#Planetary_rulerships ), and view them in Chrome on Android, they turn yellow, seemingly because they have been displayed as emojis and not as actual characters.

How can I display them as actual characters and not emojis?

Chrome 43.0.2357.93
Android 5.1.1; Nexus 7